# Helping a lethargic pigeon in the winter

Tags: birds

It's winter here, pretty cold. There's a pigeon outside my apartment building that just sits near the building and doesn't do much. It can see. It can move, but does so rarely.

I gave him bread and now I'll give him sugar water (suger/water = 1/5).
What else can I do to help it? I'll probably buy some bird seeds as well.
Can I take him at home? I have cats, but can leave the pigeon in a separate room where the cat's can't catch him.

tl;dr what to give to/ do for a pigeon that just sits outside on the ground in the winter.

I consider him an important part of the community and my life - ***he's exactly like a pet to me. An outdoors pet, but still pet.***

Answer (score 3):

I have limited experience with birds, but it's my understanding that they rarely show any signs of illness until they are very ill. So this poor pigeon may be at death's door already. Trapping it will cause stress, which may kill it. However, putting it in a warm place could be beneficial. Vets will sometimes put ill birds into a very warm room as a first step in treatment.

It's a difficult choice. The middle-ground is to keep doing what you are doing, providing food and water and hoping for the best.

I suggest you try to find someone who keeps pigeons (google "racing pigeons", "pigeon fancier", etc.), and ask their advice about whether or not to try to trap this pigeon to bring it inside, and the best way to trap it if you decide to do so. I think a pigeon keeper might be more help than a vet for this step.

Answer (score 0):

Find your local Wildlife Rescue Facility or veterinary clinic and bring any wild bird (pigeons included) there.

Comment: I'd like to keep this answer; it may be what is best for the animal. I suggest editing in that the animal may be ill - hence taking it to the vet. I'd also like to add that there are bird shelters, animal shelters specifically for birds.